# get_post() function returns post even if it is trashed

Tags: theme-development, themes, trash

I'm developing a WordPress theme. I am selecting one post as a 'featured post' from the customizer settings. I want to display this post differently on home page. I'm using following code to get the post on home.php:

```
$featured_post = get_post( get_theme_mod( 'featured_post_id' ) );
```

This code works perfectly to get the post. But, after selecting this post as a featured post, if I trash it, it still gets displayed as a featured post on home page. If I 'Delete it Permanently', it doesn't get displayed.

How do I use `get_post()` to get the post that is not trashed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how `get_post()` works. Trashing the post doesn't change the value of the theme mod, and the theme mod is still going to point to that post in the database, so `get_post()` will dutifully retrieve it as long as it's there.

It's up to you to make sure its status is what you want before display:

```
$featured_post = get_post( get_theme_mod( 'featured_post_id' ) );

if ( $featured_post && $featured_post->post_status === 'publish' ) {
    // Display post
}
```

You could also do a `WP_Query` or `get_posts()` (plural) to query posts with the status `publish` *and* the ID that you have, but it's probably going to end up more lines of code and slightly slower than just checking the status anyway.